# Example of how to create UDP sockets in C++

Tags: c++, network-programming

I have been searching the internet for an example of UDP socket creation using C++ but all I get are examples using C. Can anybody please help me with a C++ example? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small side note, there is nothing really wrong in using sockets in C++ as the C tutorials instruct. It will not be pretty, but perfectly OK otherwise. But as washington already pointed out, if you want to have something that actually looks and feels like C++, use Boost Asio.